# the did Update To location is not being called

Tags: swift, core-location, cllocationmanager

I've just started working with maps and locations . I've added the required code to the info.plist as (right after `<dict>`) :

```
<key>NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription</key>
    <string>Can we use your location?</string>
    <key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
    <string>Can we use your location?</string>
```

However I cant get the function called and as a result I dont have any output

```
import UIKit
import CoreLocation


class ViewController: UIViewController , CLLocationManagerDelegate {

   var locationManeger = CLLocationManager()



    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


        locationManeger.delegate = self
        locationManeger.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        locationManeger.startUpdatingLocation()



    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }



    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateToLocation newLocation: CLLocation, fromLocation oldLocation: CLLocation) {


    print("got the location ")



    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My dear Friend if You are testing in simulator. run your app and select simulator and select Debug tab from upside and in hardware select Location and in location select Apple instead of None
Debug->Location->Apple

its will call your method . but it will show apple as a location but if you want proper location you have to check in iphone
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Add only below in plist

```
<key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
<string>Can we use your location?</string>
```

Comment: Are you testing on device or simulator?

Comment: Simulator  @Sandeep Kumar

Comment: Did you selected simulate location option

Comment: yeah i did and now it works perfectly thanks for ur help :) @Sandeep Kumar